# How to backup Oracle Production Database without stopping service?

Tags: oracle

I have a Oracle 18XE database

I would like to create a backup for the database.

I did :

```
expdp sysdba full=y dumpfile=expdat.dmp directory=DatabaseDumps transportable=always logfile=export.log
```

But this command asks for the tablespaces to be in readonly. Wich I can not do in a production database running 24h/7.

Is there any other way to backup a database whitout stopping it or making it readonly ?

Thanks.
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best tool to create a backup database is rman.

```
sqlplus "/  as sysdba"
ALTER DATABASE FORCE LOGGING;     -- If you have tablespaces with nologging option
alter system checkpoint global;   -- To flash sga data to disk before backup
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;      -- To do a whole cycle of redologs
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
ALTER SYSTEM SWITCH LOGFILE;
rman target /
-- to open a channel to write the backup
CONFIGURE CHANNEL DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT   '/internal/backup/RMAN_001/full01_%I_%n_%T_%u_%s_%p'; 
-- to ensure the controlfile backup
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON;             
-- to open a channel to write the oracle controlfile.
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP FORMAT FOR DEVICE TYPE DISK TO '/internal/backup/RMAN_001/%F_Autobackup'; # default 
-- backup database with controlfile and archivelogs so you will recover the database to a specific point in the time between backup and backup
BACKUP AS BACKUPSET DATABASE INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG = 'RMAN_001';
```

Comment: a downvote from me. a lot o funny statements. please do not post only code. maybe you can add some explanation why you execute a specific statements

Comment: OK , I'm going to edit the commands with some comments

Comment: there is no reason to do this before every backup.. And there maybe a reason not to enable this on a database. there is no reason to do nine "alter system switch logfile". Not even on "alter system switch logfile".is necessary because it will be executed by rman automatically.. there is also not reason to do a "configure" statement before each backup. but there are good reasons to do archivelog backups frequenlty, but you dont.

Comment: rman is a world, you can make a backup in infinite different ways, my complete script has many more commands using CONFIGURE but the essence of how to make a backup is in the lines that I have put and it will work

Comment: You're right is not mandatore to use CONFIGURE because you can set the rman environment a this enviroment will be persitent but y did copy-paste of the main block of code of our scripts,  we do this because we have a lot of oracle databases and our script set always the same environment before to backup with rman because somebody could change some environment parameter.

Comment: jesus. for MSSQL it's just the `osql.exe` command. oracle lol what a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

RMAN is the best tool for performing actual backups of your files. If the database is in Archivelog mode you can do backups without shutting down. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/bradv/toc.htm

https://youtu.be/RaD3rAQNSVc

As far as datapump goes, it is fine for logical backups of the data, but not the physical files. You used the option for transportable tablespaces, which requires the tablespaces to be read only. Don't use transportable tablespaces and it should work fine.

Comment: One point however: the OP is about 18c XE. I’m not sure this one comes will a fully functional RMAN ...  Can someone confirm it does ? I could not find anything clear from the 18cXE doc.

Comment: @AlbertGodfrind There are some rman features like parallel recovery which are restricted to enterprise edition but the basic rman features are part of all editions.